# Using a CountIf statement in an If statement

Tags: excel, if-statement, countif, vba

I am trying to write an `If` statement in VBA using the `CountIf` function to check if a certain string exists in a column but I am getting a compile error. Does anyone have any idea what I am doing wrong?

This is my code:

```
Dim result as string

If CountIf(C8:C15, "FAIL") > 0 Then result = "FAIL"*
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this (after changing the worksheet name):

```
If WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("C8:C15"), "FAIL") > 0 Then result = "FAIL"
```